# Помогите создать трёхуровневое меню на css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите создать трёхуровневое меню на css на подобии этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё на самом деле очень просто, и не нужен никакой js. Обычное наследование в css

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.main-menu{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#444;
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#eee;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: auto;
}
.main-menu > .main-list{
  line-height:50px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.main-menu > .main-list:hover{
  background-color:#eee;
  color:#555;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu{
  display:none;
  list-style:none;
}
.main-menu > .main-list:hover > .second-menu{
  display:block;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list:hover{
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list{
  height:50px;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu{
  display:none;
  margin-left:100%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  list-style:none;
  color:#eee;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu > .third-list{
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#777;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu > .third-list:hover{
  background-color:#566
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list:hover > .third-menu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-list">Menu 1
      <ul class="second-menu">
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-list">Menu 2
      <ul class="second-menu">
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-list">Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!